# Scrape category info from web for an excel list

Tags: html, vba, web, web-scraping

I am completely new in web scraping of html to excel. I need to search for a part# (which is in column A of excel sheet) on a fixed website (for which I was able to find direct query link after going through several tutorials) and then note down the full category path from that web page into column B corresponding cell.

For example,  I have total 500 parts# in excel sheet column A from A2 to A500 and I want the required web information to be scraped in B2 to B500.

[image]

The information that I need to be scraped is in the html source of the page once it opens up which looks like below. the information I need is: `browse/Fasteners/Pins-Clips-Retaining-Rings/Pins-Clips/Quick-Release-Pins-Accessories/Quick-Release-Pins`

[image]

The VBA needs to pickup the MFG# from the cell A2 and and pass it as an input to VBA to open link `https://www.mscdirect.com/browse/?searchterm=XXXX`
here XXXX is the MFG# that will come from A2.
once the page loads, the path needs to be scraped and saved to column B cell. This needs to be repeated until all the the cells with data in column A have been scraped.

There maybe time when this direct search query link may give multiple results or no result at all and hence the element we are looking to scarpe wouldn't be there. In that case, I want the VBA to return something like "not found" or "multiple results" or any such message.

I also understand that there is a way with which we need not to open the internet explorer and the information to be scraped can be saved outside separately and then passed onto the excel sheet. This will save a lot of time in the whole operation. I would be very thankful if someone could help.

Here is the code that I took from a post and I was able to open the page in IE and search for the part# and nothing else. I really have not much clue on this as I am new.

```
Sub GetClassNames()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument

Dim objIE As Object

Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter

Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://www.mscdirect.com/browse/?searchterm=" & Range("A2").Text

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


Set HTML = objIE.document

Set elements = HTML.getElementsByClassName("section")

For Each element In elements
    If element.className = "section" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = element.innerText
        y = y + 1
    End If

Next element

End Sub
```

**Update:** Ok So I was able to code it and it is working as required along with error handler. However the issue that I am facing now is that after the macros runs for 50 or 60 rows, the internet explorer crash closes and after that, the macros fills all the remaining rows in column B with error handler statement "not found"
Is there a way to get around this? I would prefer if we can eliminate the dependency on Internet explorer and code this in a way so that the html is fetched out of IE. I read a lot of articles suggesting this but can't accomplish it. I would really appreciate if someone could help.
I have already tried below troubleshooting:

1. I have set the page load state to complete but doesn't make any difference and 7 secs is much more than enough for this page.
2. I have tried setting IR visibility to False but still crashes

Below is the new code I am using

```
enter code here

Sub MSC_Working()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sDD As String
    Dim CurrentTime As Date
    Dim EndingTime As Date
    

    IE.Visible = True 'IE window will be visible

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow

        IE.navigate ("https://www.mscdirect.com/browse/?searchterm=" & Cells(i, 1).Value)

        CurrentTime = Now
        EndingTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:07") '7 secs delay to allow laoding the page
        Do Until CurrentTime >= EndingTime
        DoEvents
        CurrentTime = Now()
        Loop

        Set Doc = IE.document

        sDD = Doc.getElementById("breadcrumbval").innerText 'Elelment id for required data
        Cells(i, 2) = sDD
            
NextRow:
    Next


     Set IE = Nothing
     Set Doc = Nothing
     
     Exit Sub
     
ErrHandler: 'action to take by error handler when the breadcrumbval element is not found on the page
    Err.Clear
    Cells(i, 2) = "Not found"
    Resume NextRow
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the code you are currently using so that someone can help you.

Comment: Thanks I have added the code now but it almost nothing to what I am looking to achieve